Unable to get usb permission in android sdk 34
I am trying to get permissions to read from a connected USB device. Starting from SDK 34, pending intents must be declared explicitly if they should be mutable. I do that. Still, the intent in onReceive() always has an empty extras map, no matter whether I press OK or cancel in the request popup. This issue seems to be new to SDK 34, before one could just make the PendingIntent mutable directly. Here is what I tried:
private const val ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "USB_PERMISSION"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        val usbManager = getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
        val permissionIntent = Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION)
        permissionIntent.putExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)
        permissionIntent.putExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE, "")
        permissionIntent.setPackage(this.packageName)
        val p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, permissionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

        //val p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val usbReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                Log.d("USB", "Received callback")
                if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION == intent.action) {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                        if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                            Log.d("USB", "permission granted for device $device")
                        } else {
                            Log.d("USB", "permission denied for device $device")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        registerReceiver(usbReceiver, IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), RECEIVER_EXPORTED)


        setContent {
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    for (dev in usbManager.deviceList.values) {
                        usbManager.requestPermission(dev, p)
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                Text(text = "Button")
            }
        }
    }
}

